# How to check if a certain extension is installed in browser using webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am looking for a way to find out if a certain or list of plugins/extensions are installed in the visitor's browser, who is visiting my site/webpage.
i did a little research and found out that its restricted via the extensions, so to make sure i am asking this question.
thanks and regards.
Ayaz

Comment: What extension? some extensions leave traces behind, others don't.

Comment: What do you need to know this for? This can be seen as a privacy issue as it can be used (in combination with other techniques) to identify the user. Also extensions and plugins are different.

Comment: i was planning on optimizing the site experience in a way that for example if buffer is installed in chrome, user will see a buffer bookmark button, otherwise won't. something like that.